# jquery offset() to get offset info for each() img, but only returning for 1 image (probably the last image in the set of elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the offset() for each of the images in a set of thumbnail images, then i use this offset() info to set the "left" css property of the caption popup to display directly above the thumbnail. I only need the offset().left for each img thumbnail.

```
$("#pager a img").each(function(){

var currentName = $(this).attr("src");
var theNumToSub = currentName.length - 4;

$(this).hover(function(e){
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").substr(0,theNumToSub)+"selected.jpg");
    $(this).parent().find(".caption").css("display","block");

    var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).parent().find(".caption").css("left", e.pageX - parentOffset.left);

    if($(this).parent().find(".caption").length < 1){
    $(this).parent().append("<div class='caption'><span>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</span><div class='arrowDown'></div></div>");
    }
});

$(this).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove(".caption");
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").substr(0,theNumToSub)+".jpg");
    $(this).parent().find(".caption").css("display","none");
});
```

});

I have used each() to seperate the Iteration but some how the offset() is not storing info for each img thumbnail. Is there a way to store this info another way?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wandile/9rpZa/

Comment: Can't spot the issue, but you could make use of some variables, instead of passing theNumToSub around, why not assign a var to $(this).attr("src").substr(0,theNumToSub) directly? Also you want to cache the jQuery objects

Comment: the main problem is the offset() part of it, i pasted the entire function for pespective as this is inside the each() function

Comment: Why don't you make a fiddle? That way it will be easier to help you

Comment: ok will give you a link shortly

Comment: here is the fiddle, i made the event a mousemove so it will be easy to see the effects, basicly the caption popup should show up directcly above the thumbnail: http://jsfiddle.net/Wandile/9rpZa/

Comment: also please note that these thumnails will be dynamic in the number of them visible at a time depending on how many slides are present

Comment: I can't figure it out, add the fiddle to the question so other users see it, that will get you an answer much quicker

Comment: You should try with this `.each()` function : `$.each($("pager a img"), function( index, value ) { ` then replace `$(this)` by `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.caption` class is set to be positionned relatively to the parent. So, each `.caption` element are, by default, positionned to 0x0y.
That's why they all look to have the same offset, they have !

You musn't base the left offset on `parentOffset` but on the corresponding `<a>` position

Comment: Im basing it on the corresponing image, but i hear what you say about the positioning of the .caption, let me play with the positioning and see what i get.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a solution for now, instead of using jQuery to align this rather use CSS to set the positions.

1) set the position of the parent of the thumnails to relative, then

2) Set the position of the caption to absolute, this will make the caption div respond respectively to the parents co-ordiates,

3) You can then use jQuery to align the caption only if the browser window hides the caption.

I will update the fiddle with this css solution.